# Relational Database - Multiple Types

Tags: mysql, database, types, relational

I'm setting up a relational database which would encompass information such as the following.

There would be a column for a name, of which there is a unique name and id for each name. For example: a, b, c.

Each a, b and c require multiple items to be created. For example, x, y and z.

If (name) -[required]> (items), then

```
a -> x, y
b -> x, y, z
c -> y, z
```

How would I store this in a database? I read using comma-seperated lists would be a bad idea, and haven't been able to think of a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: What did it say AFTER comma-separated lists are a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called an association table or a junction table.  It might be defined as:

```
create table NameItems (
    NameItemsId int not null auto_increment,
    NameId int,
    ItemId int,
    foreign key(NameId) references Names(NameId),
    foreign key(ItemId) references Items(ItemId)
);
```

This assumes that you have two other tables, `Names` and `Items` with information about those entities.

Comment: So I'd have: "a -> x", "a -> y", "b -> x", "b -> y" etc?

Comment: @user3163221 . . . Yes.  Each would be a separate row in the table.